# Use the Fitch system to prove the tautology (p ∨ ¬p). Stalled for days

Tags: logic, fitch, tautology

I'm having trouble solving this one. I've been stuck in step 9 for days now. Any help is very much appreciated.[image]

Comment: From line 8, introduce OR to get ~p|p, you have a contradiction with 1, then introduce negation with line 1.

Comment: Nothing happenes when I do that, I just get "No compatible rows selected"

Comment: Mauro Allegranza, that link you sent me does not answer my question. The explanation of how he goes from step 9 to 10 is not clear